# Access rights for directory, when you are a part of owner group

Tags: permissions, group

Right to the business, here is what I am trying to do

```
foverzar@subsystem /home> ls -aln
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4    0    0 4096 Dec 12 23:07 ./
drwxr-xr-x 17    0    0 4096 Dec  4 13:51 ../
drwx------  9 1000 1000 4096 Dec 13 22:05 foverzar/
drwxrwx---  2 1001 1001 4096 Dec 12 23:11 tor/
foverzar@subsystem /home> cd tor
cd: Permission denied: “./tor”
foverzar@subsystem /home> id foverzar
uid=1000(foverzar) gid=1000(foverzar) groups=1000(foverzar),10(wheel),1001(tor)
```

Basicaly my question is: why can't I access the dir, even if my user is the part of "tor" group and permissions are set to 770?

Comment: @Gilles Yep, it is. Marked as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Have you tried to reboot?" (c)

Ok, nevermind - I figured out that `usermod -aG tor foverzar` was executed during the same session as the above commands I was trying to execute.

And, since adding supplementary groups only affects `/etc/group` file, which is relevant only during login - nothing would work until we re-login the user.

Hope that helps for anyone else around.